# text/html vs application/x-www-form-urlencoded and FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter

Tags: http, rest, oauth, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

For a POST request, I got back a response in **text/html** format and the response body was containing the below info:

> oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_token_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_callback_confirmed=true

I made this request through `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and I throught I could read the response with `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` as `FormDataCollection` but it turned out that `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` only supports **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** format by default. So, I worked around this with the following code:

```
using (OAuthHttpClient client = new OAuthHttpClient(creds)) {

    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, new EmptyContent());
    var formatter = new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter();
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FormDataCollection>(new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() { formatter });

}
```

The question here is:

Is the response provider (in this case it is Twitter) doing it wrong by sending this response as **text/html** or should `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` support **text/html** type by default?

Comment: What's your Accept Header in the POST?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler that's a very wise comment. It is none, I didn't send any and got back this response. I will try to be explicit and see what it gives me back this time.

Comment: Btw you won't get back `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because the  `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` cannot write anything. It's readonly as you can see by taking a look at the [CanWriteType method](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/012d90328619#src%2fSystem.Net.Http.Formatting%2fFormatting%2fFormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.cs)

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I set it to `application/json` to see how it behaves and I got the same response.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I don't want for `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` to write anything.

Comment: If you were expecting to get `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` back, it must have been written by the `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter`. The `application/json` behavior is  odd.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Well, I explicitly set the content as you can see (`EmptyContent` object), and it is not `ObjectContent`. So, there is nothing to write.

Comment: Right, but you're expecting to get `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` back and if you compare it to the other Formatters logic that *would* happen by writing/serializing it using the  `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` *if* it where capable to write `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Btw., how does you controller action look like?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler IMO, the formatters for `HttpClient` are independent from ASP.NET Web API. If you don't specify one to read/write (this is achieved by extension methods in the library), `HttpClient` doesn't have any formatter knowledge.

Comment: I think we've a missunderstanding here: I'm speaking of the server side and you of the client side. The service you're mentioning is not an ASP.NET Web API but external, right?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler absolutely not. The question is all about `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` and content types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is missing some key info i.e. what is the requestUri supposed to return by default, is it a Web API service or an external one etc. It seems it's not Web API because it's little odd that it returns "text/html".

But the fact that FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter doesn't support formatting back from text/html is absolutely fine. Because why would it? "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is effectively a key-value dictionary and text/html is a rich media type.

In Web API, with the way content negotiation works, it looks at

1. Mediatype mappings (I assume not in place in your case)
2. Accept headers - looking at your request you don't set them
3. Request content type - again, looking at your request you don't set it so it's empty
4. Can the formatter serialize a given type

So if you make the request as you showed to any Web API action, it would return text/xml (if you didn't tweak conneg manually).

Comment: the question is about `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` and not about conneg. The response comes back from Twitter OAuth server.

Comment: so I included the answer - But the fact that FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter doesn't support formatting back from text/html is absolutely fine. Because why would it? "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is effectively a key-value dictionary and text/html is a rich media type. I mentioned conneg because I wasn't sure whether the response is from Web API or external service

Comment: I thought the same. I think the response provider (Twitter) doing it wrong by sending this response as **text/html**.

Comment: Exatcly. It's just Twitter has it all wrong sending the response formatted as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and decorated incorrectly with "text/html" content type. Your work around is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Filip that this is a fine work around to an incorrect content type header.

Henrik